# Paired hypothesis testing without identifiers

Tags: hypothesis-testing, paired-data

I assessed two groups with a pre and post test but didn't identify each test so I don't know which test belongs to each person. I do know which is pre and which is post though. Can I still use a hypothesis test and if so, which one?

Comment: Please provide more details about what you are testing for, what do you measure, your sample sizes, your experimental design, etc.

Comment: @usεr11852 I asked 8 students to rate themselves on a scale of 1-10 with 10 being most skilled, I then taught them all day and asked them to rate themselves again post-class but I did  not collect names so I dont know who's pre or post test is whose. I want to test if the post class group feels more skilled now that they had my instruction.

Comment: @gung: You added the `paired-data` tag but is this setting truly paired? (I accept that the data "should be" paired but I am uncertain if they should be analysed as paired here.)

Comment: @usεr11852, we don't know what the pairing is, but the data are nonetheless paired. Moreover, I think the tag is appropriate here to categorize this question.

Comment: @gung: Sorry, I probably misexpressed myself. I agree that the tag is relevant, my query was if the data could be analysed as paired in the current settting.

Comment: That's the whole question, @usεr11852. But the data are actually paired whether the answer is yes or no.

Comment: @gung: Well, I answered "no" on that matter but if you have a different opinion I would be interested to know! :D